# ¿Como seleccionar la Linea (Row) correspondiente de un jTable utilizando RowFilter?

Tags: java, select, jtable, filtro

Lo que pasa es que quiero seleccionar(mouseClicked) un producto(Row) de un jTable(jTable_productos) despues de filtrar utilizando TableRowSorter para monstrar en una otra ventana(informacionProducto). Pero el producto mostrado en la ventana informacionProducto no corresponde al producto filtrado seleccionado.  Gracias por la colaboracion!

public class ActualizarProducto extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
TableRowSorter trs1;

public ActualizarProducto() {
    initComponents();

    try {
        Connection cn = Conexion.conectar();
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("select id, tipo, producto, precio from productos");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        jTable_productos = new JTable(model);
        jScrollPane_equipos.setViewportView(jTable_productos);

        model.addColumn("ID producto");
        model.addColumn("Tipo de producto");
        model.addColumn("Producto");
        model.addColumn("Precio");

        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] fila = new Object[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                fila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            model.addRow(fila);
        }
        cn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error en el llenado de la tabla de productos");
    }
    
    jTable_productos.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int fila_point = jTable_productos.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            int columna_point = 0;

            if (fila_point > -1) {
                IDproducto_update = (int) model.getValueAt(fila_point, columna_point);
                InformacionProducto informacionProducto = new InformacionProducto();
                informacionProducto.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

}                    


private void txt_filtroKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    

    txt_filtro.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            trs1.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + txt_filtro.getText(), 2));
        }
    });

    trs1 = new TableRowSorter(model);
    jTable_productos.setRowSorter(trs1);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

encontre la soluccion:

```
jTable_productos.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      IDproducto_update = (int) jTable_productos.getValueAt(jTable_productos.getSelectedRow(), 0);
    if (IDproducto_update > 0) {
         InformacionProducto informacionProducto = new InformacionProducto();
         informacionProducto.setVisible(true);
            }
```